# Facebook Open Graph access without Facebook Connect

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to access public Facebook information, such as user's name, without using Facebook Connect?

I've been reading the docs on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/
and they have mentioned "public" information and "private" information.

It is still unclear to me if any attempt to access the visitor's facebook information requires Facebook Fonnect first.

I'm assuming the user must go through the Facebook Connect process before any data may be accessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. If you are a first timer accessing Facebook, then you have to go through FBConnect. And then if you have opted for extended permission `offline_access` your access token will never expire and you can use that token to access the facebook info without FBConnect

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but what I am wondering is can I get **any** information without FBConnect / Login? For instance, if a user visits my page, can it say Hello, <user's name> even if they've never FBConnect / login?

Comment: @Atticus: if that would be possible, then it would be a serious security breach. think of all the possibilities.

Comment: Heh, yeah thats what lead me to assume no

Comment: I noticed Pandora radio grabs your Facebook information even if you didn't connect. Is this made possible because Facebook gave them authorization to do so? Or are some things publicly available?

Comment: i cannot check pandora as its not for indian users. still it cannot identify you as a facebook user without facebook connect /  login. even facebook cannot identify you without logging in :)

Comment: Right, the thing with Pandora is if you are logged into Facebook, and a first time visitor to Pandora (ie - haven't FBConnected yet), it still greets you with your name, prof pic, and starts a playlist based off of your favorite music.. I remember logging into facebook on a public computer and visiting pandora (not signed into pandora or anything, nor have FBConnected) and it recognized me

Comment: http://www.socialtechnologyreview.com/articles/future-open-graph-and-facebook-social-plugins

 "How open are you willing to be" talks about how some sites such as Pandora, Yelp, Microsoft Docs access your Facebook (if logged into facebook at the current time of visit) without any authentication..

Comment: Pandora has a special agreement in place: https://www.facebook.com/instantpersonalization/

Comment: IMHO Facebook should not do that.I do hope that the new Google Plus has much better privacy settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can access a users public information via the graph api without an access token if you know their user id or user name.  For example these will return info:

- http://graph.facebook.com/4
- http://graph.facebook.com/zuck

The problem though is that without having an [instant personalization](https://www.facebook.com/instantpersonalization/) deal signed with Facebook, you won't be able to tell who the current user until they authenticate with your application.